# On Fedora using Qt 5.9.4, I'm unable to simultaneously record and play audio at the same time

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qaudioinput

I'm trying to write a program in Qt that simultaneously records audio from a microphone and plays it back at the same time. I'm using Qt 5.9.4 and I'm on Fedora 29 (can't update to latest version as our production environment is Fedora 29 -- can't update it, have already asked boss).

I have some barebones code written, as you can see below. But everytime I run the program, I get the following error message:

```
using null output device, none available
using null input device, none available
```

I've installed every qt5* package. I have alsa-utils and pulse audio installed as well.

I have also looked at these which more or less helped me but did not solve my problem:

- [Qt - how to record and play sound simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776022/qt-how-to-record-and-play-sound-simultaneously)
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/10399/how-to-record-and-play-sound-simultaneously/5
- https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45300-How-to-record-and-play-sound-simultaneously
- [Qt - No audio output device - Yocto/poky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660694/qt-no-audio-output-device-yocto-poky)
- [Qt + conan = using null output device, none available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569427/qt-conan-using-null-output-device-none-available)

I don't know if this is a fedora related issue or a Qt related issue. Please help!

myaudiorecorder.h:

```
 #ifndef MYAUDIORECORDER_H
 #define MYAUDIORECORDER_H

#include <QAudioFormat>
#include <QAudioDeviceInfo>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QAudioInput>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QObject>

class MyAudioRecorder : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyAudioRecorder();

    QAudioFormat formatIn;
    QAudioFormat formatOut;

    QAudioInput *m_audioInput;
    QAudioOutput *m_audioOutput;

    QAudioDeviceInfo m_InputDevice;
    QAudioDeviceInfo m_OutputDevice;

    QIODevice *m_input;
    QIODevice *m_output;

    QAudioDeviceInfo deviceIn;
    QAudioDeviceInfo deviceOut;

    void getFormat();
    void createAudioInput();
    void createAudioOutput();
    void beginAudio();

};

#endif // MYAUDIORECORDER_H
```

myaudiorecorder.cpp:

```
#include "myaudiorecorder.h"

MyAudioRecorder::MyAudioRecorder() {
    getFormat();
    createAudioInput();
    createAudioOutput();
}


void MyAudioRecorder::getFormat(){
    formatIn.setSampleSize(8);
    formatIn.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    formatIn.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    formatIn.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    deviceIn = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput).at(1);
    if(!deviceIn.isFormatSupported(formatIn)){
    QTextStream(stdout) << " default formatIn not supported " << endl;
    formatIn = deviceIn.nearestFormat(formatIn);
    } else {
    QTextStream(stdout) << " default formatIn supported " << endl;
    }

    deviceOut = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput).at(0);
    if(!deviceOut.isFormatSupported(formatOut)) {
    QTextStream(stdout) << "1. default formatOut not supported " << endl;
    formatOut = deviceOut.nearestFormat(formatOut);
    }

}


void MyAudioRecorder::createAudioInput(){
    m_audioInput = new QAudioInput(m_InputDevice, formatIn, 0);
}

void MyAudioRecorder::createAudioOutput(){
    m_audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(m_OutputDevice, formatOut, 0);
}

void MyAudioRecorder::beginAudio(){
    m_output = m_audioOutput->start();
    m_input = m_audioInput->start();
}
```

Comment: You have not set your `m_InputDevice` and `m_OutputDevice` set it to fix that null device error

Comment: @Sumit ahh okay. So this is what I added:

    m_OutputDevice = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice();
    m_InputDevice = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();

--- However, I still don't hear the audio that is being spoken into the microphone.

Comment: What are the gain settings according to amixer?

Comment: @stark alright, this is what I get when I run `$ amixer

[fac@localhost ~]$ amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 57017 [87%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 57017 [87%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Front Left: Capture 41353 [63%] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 41353 [63%] [on]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void MyAudioRecorder::beginAudio(){
    m_output = m_audioOutput->start();
    m_audioInput->start(m_output);


   //Above should do the trick but do check the volume, state and error if any:
   qDebug() << "m_audioInput: volume=" <<  m_audioInput->volume()
            << ", state=" << m_audioInput->state()
            << ", error=" << m_audioInput->error();
   qDebug() << "m_audioOutput: volume=" <<  m_audioOutput->volume()
            << ", state=" << m_audioOutput->state()
            << ", error=" << m_audioOutput->error();

}
```

Comment: General Note: If your mic is nearby speaker which catches speaker sound, then you will hear very bogus looped sound...

Comment: very interesting because this was the direction I was trying to go yesterday. So that compiles but I get this as the output for console
`m_audioInput: volume=1, state=2, error=1


m_audioOutput: volume=1, state=0, error=0 
`

I read in the docs yesterday that `m_output` should be in _The device must have been opened in the ReadOnly or ReadWrite modes._ from [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html#start) but, when I tried that [i.e. m_output->read()] it just wouldn't proceed past that line. And nothing was produced.

Comment: I almost think I should do something like this: 
`m_output = m_audioInput->start();
bool isReadWriteReady = m_output->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);`
but it crashes.

Comment: but even if I do `bool isReadWriteReady = m_output->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    m_output = m_audioInput->start();` -- that crashes as well.  @Sumit

Comment: but then the docs say _The device will already be open and read() can read data directly from it._ so that makes me think that the `QIODevice *m_output` is already set to open and that it is ready to be read from so there's no need to have `bool isReadWriteReady = m_output->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);` and what should follow is: `m_audioOutput->start(m_output);` but it is not working as intended. No audio is produced.

Comment: But for me the little change I have posted, is able to produce sound from my speaker, I tested it. Also if you print something using qDebug() then it will be more human readable for me the printed text was:
`m_audioInput: volume= 1 , state= ActiveState , error= NoError
m_audioOutput: volume= 1 , state= IdleState , error= NoError`

Comment: huh that's very interesting. Perhaps I need to rewrite the program. I'm going to try rewriting it because perhaps there's a mishap somewhere that I'm not noticing.

Comment: In documentation I read that "state = 2" means => 
`QAudio::StoppedState 2 The audio device is closed, and is not processing any audio data`

Please check in your control panel is your mic enabled and working ?? can you record something using any other program ?

Comment: okay rewrote the whole thing. turns out I needed to change it to this: `deviceIn = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();` in `getFormat()` -- though the output is incredibly staticy. Tried moving the microphone away but didn't fix the problem.

Comment: also, am getting the audio from the mic via the computer speaker output. Super staticky but it's a start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208521/discussion-between-earlyriser01-and-sumit).

Answer (score 0):

you need copy qt Qt/5.9.x/mingw73_64/plugins/audio to you binary directory,not copy qtaudio_windows.dll ,is copy audio folder

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think about that. However, with the accepted answer, I achieved my desired result. Thank you for the input though!